# Excel Charts name field auto edit

Tags: excel

I have a .ppt linked to a .xls on some charts. Looking at the path of the links, some charts are named as XPTO-1, however the name field on excel is just XPTO. Why is excel adding "-1" tag?I don't have any chart with repeated name.
This happens on 2003 version and 2007.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer guys. The excel allows different charts to have the same name on the same worksheet. This way, when you look to chart name, it is the same, but the path looks like XPTO1 for 1st chart and XPTO1-1 for the other.
This cases the break of links when these files are updated on an office 2007 version because office 2007 can't handle these ids on some situations.
The solution is to manual edit the name of charts and make sure the name is not repeated on the same worksheet.